# Is there a chess engine whose architecture is composed purely of ranked/weighted constraints that then generate candidate moves for search?

Tags: chess, constraint-satisfaction-problems

Chess can be seen as a search for a move with many constraints on it. In the human way of searching for a move, we think to ourselves something like "I need to find a move that both moves the queen while protecting my knight."

Is there a chess engine whose architecture is composed purely of ranked/weighted constraints that then generate candidate moves for search?

I know that more "brute force" algorithms are in vogue due to alpha-beta, but this architecture would have the advantage of being highly explainable to a human player.

Is anyone aware of a program with a similar hard-coded heuristics/constraint-based architecture?